# Opening a new line without returning the carriage

Tags: formatting

Say I want to begin letters like this:

```
Dear world,
           hello.
```

What's the simplest way to define a mapping that opens a new line preserving the cursor's horizontal position?

Comment: And perhaps next you will ask, "And the most correct way?" :)

Comment: Not really a vi/Vim answer, but you may want to learn about vertical tabs.  For terminal-specific files they can be handy.

Comment: @Wildcard, what are they?

Comment: See for yourself: `printf '%s\v%s\n' hello there` (at a command prompt).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this using no vimscript is the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>o yyp^v$r A
```

This assumes you want to start the mapping in normal mode (otherwise just add `<Esc>` to the beginning of your insert mode mapping).
It copies the current line with `yy`, pastes it on the line below (`p`), selects the pasted text in visual mode (`^v$`), replaces the selection with whitespaces (`r` followed by a space) and jumps to the end, putting you in insert mode (`A`).